# pattern recognition of microscopy images with python

Tags: python, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I would like to find a zoomed microscopy image in a dozen of overview images. I would prefer to find some python/numpy/scipy solution.
My knowledge about pattern recognition is negligible. Anyway, here is what I tried:

My first idea was to get the most important structures out of the images by 
setting eveything greater[smaller] than some threshold to 255[0] in the greyscaled image.

For example, I then have the following pattern:

[image]

The overview image might then look like this:

[image: overview image including the pattern]

Here is a version where the region of the pattern is highlighted:

[image]

I would now like to find a way to get the pixel number, at which the pattern occurs in the overview image.

It is very important to note, that I do not have information about:

- the orientation of the two images with respect to each other
- the scaling of the images
- in principle, there might even be some stretching between the images, but this might be too hard to implement.
- I do no know if the pattern is on the image. There I have to check about 20 images.

For a fixed scaling, my attempt was to use

```
result = scipy.signal.fftconvolve()
```

and see how the maximum of `result` then varies when I rotate the pattern before doing the convolution.
Taking the maximum value gives me the correct angle at which the images overlap.

However this is not a nice solution because it already takes some minutes. Also varying the scaling and even doing further transformations would take forever.

I guess there are better approaches out there!

Comment: Not a trivial problem. Reducing the resolution of the zoomed in images would be helpful since they do contain information that you can't match to the overview images anyway. So I'd do the comparison in the Fourier domain. Having some knowledge about scaling would still be helpful, so look at your workflow and see if you can keep the scaling constant, otherwise the cutoffs in the FFT frequencies would have to adaptive too.  In the example you gave there is no rotations and the scale is 1:1. Also your thresholding is the same for overview and detail so you appear to have some prior knowledge.

Comment: @roadrunner66 thank you for your advices. I will keep them in mind. Indeed, in the example the scale is 1:1 and there is no rotation. However, this is only because I rotated and scaled the images already by hand. This is not possible in general since I don't know whether or not they overlap at all.
It would be possible to include some knowledge about rotation and scaling. The point is that both need quite some work that I was hoping to skip with some great recognition algorithm.